# Java script not running

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my html code with javascript validations.... HTML elements are showing well javascript function is not working.....

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>SIGNUP</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function valid(fname,sname,login,name,tstest,mailf,mails){
var namef=fname.value;
var names=sname.value;
var logn=login.value;
var name1=name.value;
var ts=tstest.value;
var mailf=mail1.value;
var mails=.mail2.value;
if(namef=="")   <!-- validating the field first name-->
{
   window.alert("please enter name.");
   fname.focus();
 }
else if(names=="")<!-- validating the field second name-->
{
  window.alert("please enter password");
 sname.focus();
 }
 else if(names<=6)
     {
  window.alert("Password should be more than 6 characters");
  sname.focus();
  }
 else if(logn=="")<!-- validating the login field-->
 {
   window.alert("please enter email.");
  login.focus();
  }
 else if(name1=="")<!-- validating the password field-->
  {
    window.alert("please enter confirm password.");
      name.focus();
   }
      else if(name1!=names)
    {
     window.alert("Password Mismatch");
        name.focus();
      }
          else if(ts=="")<!-- validating the date field-->
       {
            alert("please enter contact number.");
              tstest.focus();
        }
          else if(ts<10)
         {
       alert("Contact Number Should be Minimum 10 numbers");
       tstest.focus();
          }
             else if(mailf=="")<!-- validating the mail field-->
          {
            alert("please enter qualification.");
               mail1.focus();
          }
          else if(mails=="")<!-- validating the 2nd mail field-->
             {
                alert("please enter interested in.");
     mail2.focus();
     }
      }

        }
    </script>
            </head>
               <body>
              <center>
            <div id="border"><div id="header">
                <div id="logo-bg">
                    <div class="name">Ayansys</div>
                    <div class="tag">COMPANY SLOGAN</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1>SIGNUP FORM</h1>
            <form name="sign"                                   onsubmit="valid(fname,sname,login,pwd,tstest,mail1,mail2)" >
                <table name="signuptable">
                    <tr><td>FIRST NAME</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>LAST NAME</td><td><input type="text" name="sname" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>DESIRED LOGIN NAME</td><td><input type="text" name="login" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>PASSWORD</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>RE-TYPE PASSWORD</td><td><input type="password" name="repwd" size="50"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>GENDER</td><td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="FeMale"/>Female</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>DATE OF BIRTH</td><td><form name="tstest">
                     <input type="text" readonly size="47" name="timestamp" value="">
                                                    <a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp', document.tstest.timestamp.value);"><img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp"></a>
                                                    </form></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>MAIL ID</td><td><input type="text" name="mail1" size="30">@<input type="text" name="mail2" size="11"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>EMPLOYEE ID</td><td><input type="text" name="eid" size="50"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>TYPE OF USER</td><td><input type="radio" name="manager"/>Manager<input type="radio" name="manager"/>SeniorManager</td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>ADDRESS</td><td><textarea rows="9" cols="40" name="addr"></textarea></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>MOBILE NUMBER</td><td><input type="text" size="50" name="mobile"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="sign" value="SUBMIT">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="cancel" value="CANCEL"/></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            </form>
                </br><div>Designed by:<a href="#">STUDY CENTER</a></div>
          </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: "Not running" is a very poor description of a problem.  Have you checked the error console in your browser for an error message?  Also, do you realize that `<!-- -->` is a syntax error in JavaScript?  `//` and `/* */` delimit comments in JS.

Comment: use firebug or any other console to see the errors you've made...

Comment: I tried every possible way to get the output,i even checked through the error console also..but its not working..

Comment: *but its not working*... again, a very poor description of the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest learning to use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).  It will help you find most syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

line 13, you have a "dot" 
`mails=.mail2.value;`

line 66 syntax error you had a wrong placed brace

try removing the dot and the brace and see if it works as expeted

pulse `window.alert()` , you only need to use `alert()`
and your redeclaring you variables

your onsubmit argument `mail2` differs from the expeted one `mails`